# How to shuffle lists in Prolog while preserving inner order

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to print out all possible shuffled variants of two lists in one list while preserving the order.

I need to write a predicate shuffle(`L1`, `L2`, `L3`) which shuffles `L1` and `L2` and puts the result into `L3` while preserving the inner order of `L1` and `L2`.

For example :

```
?- shuffle([a,b],[1,2],L).
L = [a,b,1,2] ;
L = [a,1,b,2] ;
L = [a,1,2,b] ;
L = [1,a,b,2] ;
L = [1,a,2,b] ;
L = [1,2,a,b]
```

What I have so far :

```
shuffle([],[],[]).
shuffle([X|Xs],[Y|Ys],[X,Y|Tail]) :-
    shuffle(Xs,Ys,Tail).
shuffle([X|Xs],[Y|Ys],[Y,X|Tail]) :-
    shuffle(Xs,Ys,Tail).
```

This results in :

```
| ?- shuffle([a,b],[1,2],L).
L = [a,1,b,2] ? ;
L = [a,1,2,b] ? ;
L = [1,a,b,2] ? ;
L = [1,a,2,b]
```

So I'm missing the cases of "simple append" of `L1+L2` and `L2+L1`...

What is my predicate missing?

Comment: Clearly, the clauses you have so far do not describe all possible cases. Think of a simple case that should work, but currently does not. Then think about which additional clause would make it succeed. Also: Think about a case where L1 and L2 do not have the same length!

Comment: @mat
When I added shuffle(X,[],X).and shuffle([],Y,Y). it just resulted in many duplicate cases so I can't think of what I can do here...

Comment: Nevertheless, a step in the right direction. First, focus on covering all relevant cases. Later, you can work on reducing duplicates by making the clauses mutually exclusive!

Comment: @mat
As I wrote in the question, I realize which cases are missing but I don't understand how to write the cases in prolog : (

Comment: @mat
shuffle([],[],[]).
shuffle(X,[],X).
shuffle([],Y,Y).
shuffle([X|Xs],[Y|Ys],[X,Y|Tail]) :-
 shuffle(Xs,Ys,Tail).
shuffle([X|Xs],[Y|Ys],[Y,X|Tail]) :-
 shuffle(Xs,Ys,Tail).
shuffle(X,Y,List) :-
 append(X,Y,List).
shuffle(X,Y,List) :-
 append(Y,X,List).

That's where I am at but I get a lot of duplicate results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) for its ease of writing:

```
shuffle([A|B],[C|D]) --> [A] , shuffle(B,[C|D]). 
shuffle([A|B],[C|D]) --> [C] , shuffle([A|B],D).
shuffle(A,[]) --> A.
shuffle([],C) --> C.

shuffle( A, B, C) :- phrase( shuffle(A,B), C).
```

We either take first card from one non-empty deck or the other, but if one of them is empty we must use all the remaining cards in the non-empty deck at once.

Unfortunately this leaves one extra choice point at the end:

```
5 ?- shuffle([a,b],[1,2],C).
C = [a, b, 1, 2] ;
C = [a, 1, b, 2] ;
C = [a, 1, 2, b] ;
C = [1, a, b, 2] ;
C = [1, a, 2, b] ;
C = [1, 2, a, b] ;
false.
```

As for your approach the problem with it was that you tried to take care of two cards at once, and it got complicated. Going by smallest steps can be the easiest.

Comment: dcg just makes it easier to write it down. it is straightforward and mechanical to re-write it as "normal" predicates. e.g. `shuffle([A|B],[C|D]) --> [A] , shuffle(B,[C|D]).` is `shuffle([A|B],[C|D],X,Z) :- X=[A|Y] , shuffle(B,[C|D],Y,Z). ` look up [tag:difference-lists].

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can shuffle two lists while preserving the relative item order.

```
shuffle([], Xs, Xs).
shuffle([X|Xs], Ys, Zs) :-
   shuffle_(Ys, X, Xs, Zs).          % use auxiliary predicate shuffle_/4

shuffle_([], X, Xs, [X|Xs]).         % do indexing on both lists
shuffle_([Y|Ys], X, Xs, [X|Zs]) :-
   shuffle_(Xs, Y, Ys, Zs).
shuffle_([Y|Ys], X, Xs, [Y|Zs]) :-
   shuffle_(Ys, X, Xs, Zs).
```

Sample query using SWI-Prolog:

```
?- shuffle([a,b], [1,2], Xs).
   Xs = [a,1,b,2]
;  Xs = [a,1,2,b]
;  Xs = [a,b,1,2]
;  Xs = [1,a,2,b]
;  Xs = [1,a,b,2]
;  Xs = [1,2,a,b].                   % no useless choice point at the end
```

Answer (score 1):

@repeat's answer is more elegant and efficient, but, as an alternative:

The unwanted choice-point can be removed using a reusable `empty_list_first` predicate:

```
shuffle([A|B], [C|D]) --> [A],
    shuffle(B, [C|D]).
shuffle([A|B], [C|D]) --> [C],
    { empty_list_first([A|B], D, A1, D1) },
    shuffle(A1, D1).

% Rewritten to prevent needing https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=basics
%shuffle([], C) --> remainder(C).
shuffle([], C, C, []).

shuffle(A, B, C) :-
    empty_list_first(A, B, A1, B1),
    phrase(shuffle(A1, B1), C).

empty_list_first([], L2, [], L2).
empty_list_first([H|T], L2, EL1, EL2) :-
    empty_list_first_(L2, [H|T], EL1, EL2).

empty_list_first_([], L1, [], L1).
% If neither are empty, keep original order
empty_list_first_([H|T], L1, L1, [H|T]).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- shuffle([a,b], [1,2], C).
C = [a,b,1,2] ;
C = [a,1,b,2] ;
C = [a,1,2,b] ;
C = [1,a,b,2] ;
C = [1,a,2,b] ;
C = [1,2,a,b].
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is posted long time after original question but hoping this might prove useful to someone some day. I've taken a different approach to this, might be on the longer side but it works... :)
Since one of the requirements at the class I'm taking to not exceed material learned, some items such as delete and concatenate have been created here as well.

```
del(X,[X|Xs],Xs).
del(X,[Y|Ys],[Y|Zs]):-
    del(X,Ys,Zs).

permutation([],[]).
permutation(Xs,[Z|Zs]):-
    del(Z,Xs,Ys),
permutation(Ys,Zs).

conc([],L,L).
conc([X|L1],L2,[X|L3]):-
    conc(L1,L2,L3).

is_in_order([],_).
is_in_order([_],_).
is_in_order(Sublist1, Sublist2, Superlist) :-
    remove_elements(Superlist, Sublist1, SuperSubList),
    list_equal(Sublist2, SuperSubList).

list_equal([], []).
list_equal([X|Xs],[X|Ys]) :-
    list_equal(Xs, Ys).

% Remove L1 from L2 and return the resulting list
remove_elements(L, [H|T], R) :-
    delete(L, H, R1),
    remove_elements(R1, T, R).
remove_elements(L, [], L).

/*Shuffle first creates a concatenated list from both L1 & L2
 * It then create permutation for all possible combinations of L1 & L2
 * Once done, it scrubs the new lists to filter out the ones that do not 
 * maintain the original order of L1 & L2
 * The result is only the permutations that fullfills the order condition
*/

shuffle(L1,L2,L):-
    conc(L1,L2,L3),
    permutation(L3, L),
    is_in_order(L1, L2, L),
    is_in_order(L2, L1, L).
```